# How to print shell script stdout/stderr to file/s and console

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr, tee

In the bash script I use the following syntax I order to print everything from the script to the files - `$file` and `$sec_file`

we are running the script on our Linux rhel server - version 7.8

```
exec > >(tee -a "$file" >>"$sec_file") 2>&1
```

so after bash script completed , we get on both files the content of `stdout/stderr` of every line in the bash script

now we want additionally to print to the console the `stdout/stderr` and not only to the files

I will appreciate of any suggestion

Example of the script:

```
# more  /tmp/script.bash

#!/bin/bash

file=/tmp/file.txt
sec_file=/tmp/sec_file.txt

exec > >(tee -a "$file" >>"$sec_file") 2>&1

echo "hello world , we are very happy to stay here "
```

Example how to run the script:

```
/tmp/script.bash

<--  no output from the script -->

# more /tmp/file.txt
hello world , we are very happy to stay here
# more /tmp/sec_file.txt
hello world , we are very happy to stay here
```

example of expected output that should be as the following

```
/tmp/script.bash
hello world , we are very happy to stay here
```

and

```
# more /tmp/file.txt
hello world , we are very happy to stay here
# more /tmp/sec_file.txt
hello world , we are very happy to stay here
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the two files to contain exactly the same text after the execution?

Comment: yes both files should capture the stdout and stderr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the easiest is to just add multiple files as arguments to the `tee` like this:

```
% python3 -c 'import sys; print("to stdout"); print("to stderr", file=sys.stderr)' 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/file.txt /tmp/file_sec.txt
to stdout
to stderr
% cat /tmp/file.txt 
to stdout
to stderr
% cat /tmp/file_sec.txt 
to stdout
to stderr
```

Your script would look like this then:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/tmp/file.txt
sec_file=/tmp/sec_file.txt

exec > >(tee -a "$file" "$sec_file") 2>&1

echo "hello world , we are very happy to stay here "
```

Comment: There's no need for the additional tee - `echo "ok" | tee -a file1 file2 filen` works fine

Comment: right, the simplest solutions are overlooked so easily... I updated the answer

Comment: but what we need is about bash script , and solution must be inside the script , and not using tee outside from the script

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can use that anywhere. In scripts or on the command line.

Comment: what I mean is that - you gives example of python , but we are talking here on bash , seconed I want to avoid solution by adding the tee with pipe line on the script , solution should be inside the script and not by adding pipeline with the script

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for you. The python was just a "lazy demo" thing.

Comment: now according to your update I see little problem , script not ended , its like script is hang inspite its works

Comment: For me it prints the stuff and exits as I would expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219394/discussion-between-jessica-and-toydarian).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just write console things to a new output channel:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=file.txt
sec_file=sec_file.txt

exec 4>&1 > >(tee -a "$file" >>"$sec_file") 2>&1

echo "stdout"
echo "stderr" >&2
echo "to the console" >&4
```

Output:

```
me@pc:~/⟫ ./script.sh 
to the console
me@pc:~/⟫ cat file.txt 
stdout
stderr
me@pc:~/⟫ cat sec_file.txt 
stdout
stderr
```

If you want you can do this and even write to stderr again with `>&5`:

```
exec 4>&1 5>&1 > >(tee -a "$file" >>"$sec_file") 2>&1
echo "stderr to console" >&5
```

Edit: Changed `&3` to `&4` as `&3` is sometimes used for stdin.

But maybe this is the moment to rethink what you are doing and keep `&1` stdout and `&2` stderr and use `&4` and `&5` to write to file?

```
exec 4> >(tee -a "$file" >>"$sec_file") 5>&1
```

This does require you though to add to all lines that should end up in your file to prepend `>&4 2>&5`

Comment: I try it but this not print to console

Comment: I tried it on `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` which seems the same version as you are using, and for me my first snippet works. Did you notice I changed your exec line a bit? Did you copy the whole script or just part of it?